# Running python code in playwright container

Tags: python, docker, containers, playwright

I have pulled and run the official playwright docker container: https://playwright.dev/python/docs/docker/

However, when I run `docker run -it --rm --ipc=host mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:focal /bin/bash`

And enter `python` and then try to import playwright it can't find it. Am I doing something wrong here? Any guidance much appreciated!

Comment: You need to install Playwright for Python inside the container via `pip install playwright`. After that you can import it via Python.

Answer (score -2):

in the docker, you don't need to go inside python.
Just run from bash:

```
$ npx playwright open google.com
```

For more options, check out the doc: https://playwright.dev/docs/cli/